# Encrypting region in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have been trying to write a small function to encrypt contents of file in emacs. Here are the steps I followed :

- Select all (`C-x h`)
- `M-x epa-encrypt-region RET`
- `C-c C-c`

After these steps, emacs will prompt for the password and the file will be encrypted. This is the function I wrote :

```
(defun encrypt ()
  "encrypt file"
  (interactive)
  (command-execute (kbd "C-x h M-x epa-encrypt-region RET C-c C-c"))
  )

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-e") 'encrypt)
```

But there seems to be something wrong with it. Please help me fix this.

Comment: Trying to understand your problem here. The code you wrote works. It takes the content of the buffer, encrypts it, and uses the encrypted part to replace the original part. You need to explain what you think is wrong for people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function `epa-encrypt-file` instead of writing it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to know where you found the suggestion to use `command-execute` and `kbd` in that way. It seems like a generally *valid* thing to do, but it's clearly not the most sensible option here (and rarely ever would be). I think this is literally the first time I've seen it.

In short, don't try to fake the process of calling a function interactively if there's no need to do that.

```el
(epa-encrypt-region (point-min) (point-max) nil nil nil)
```

Comment: The documentation of `epa-encrypt-region` recommends not using it in Lisp programs.

Comment: Thomas: Very true, but not actually an issue in this case as we are only talking about making a wrapper around its interactive functionality.

Comment: Well, the original question starts with "I have been trying to write a small function to encrypt contents of file in emacs." I would think that either `epa-encrypt-string` or `epa-encrypt-file` (both recommended over `epa-encrypt-region` by the documentation) would be suitable for the job. Writing a wrapper for key strokes was sudeepdino008's initial approach, but that doesn't mean it's the best way.

Comment: Fair point; I *was* assuming that sudeepdino008 was aware of `epa-encrypt-file` (in particular) and had intentionally rejected it, and the code given was indicative of the desired end-result.

Comment: I won't mind a better solution. My method seemed to me innovative, but I would love a simple solution.

Comment: What do you not like about `epa-encrypt-file`?

Comment: @sudeepdino008, has your question been answered?

Comment: @NicolasDudebout I somehow easier when I tried epa-encrypt-region long time ago. Just give me a bit of code and the reason why epa-encrypt-file is better and I am good.

Comment: What is your goal/expected behavior? For example, where do you want the encrypted version of the file to live? Another file or the current file...? What you wrote in your question is a rewrite of `epa-encrypt-file`.